# Fedora 33-34 failed upgrade, likely because of RDMA-core bug?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, crash

First time posting here, sorry if my formatting is wrong. I'll happily fix this post if necessary. Also I'm still fairly new to Linux, so I'd greatly appreciate if any instructions given are detailed.

I upgraded from Fedora Workstation 33 to 34 on my desktop the other day. After completing the upgrade, however, it fails to boot. When I first tried to boot into my system, I got the following two error messages listed several times after selecting any of the 3 kernel version listed in the grub bootloader:

> failed to mount /boot//efi when booting in rescue mode

> something else that mentioned virtualization not working (possibly was a DEPEND, not a FAILED)

I can't seem to get these errors to repeat, so I'm not sure on what the second one said exactly. When I try the same thing now, the computer defaults to rescue mode, not showing these errors at all anymore.

When booting into rescue mode, it also fails, saying the following:

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details.  Press Enter to continue.

Pressing enter just loops back into these same messages.

When I upgraded from 33 to 34, I used the Gnome Software Center to do it. I recall seeing a warning message saying something along the lines of the following before continuing:

> RDMA-core will be removed during installation

Looking around online, I found [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F34_bugs#Upgrade_to_Fedora_34_may_fail_if_i686_rdma-core_package_installed) that mentions this as a common bug, and links to [a Red Hat Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1919864) (that doesn't seem to have a solution that works for me). It also links to [a page on the FedoraProject site that has download links for various versions of RDMA-core](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/rdma-core). I'm pretty sure the version I need is "rdma-core-36.0-1.fc34" because I'm now (supposedly) running Fedora34, but I'm not sure how to go about installing it from the .rpm file when I can't boot into my system, even in rescue mode.

I've tried booting from a LiveUSB, and I can access most of my system files from there, but I can't figure out how to install the .rpm file using the LiveUSB of FedoraWorkstation34 onto my pre-existing partitions. When I try to open the .rpm file, it opens the Gnome Software Center with an error message that says "Failed to install file: not supported".

Any help towards fixing this would be greatly appreciated. I think (but could easily be wrong) that I need to either install RDMA-core onto my system, overwrite the boot/efi partition, revert back to Fedora 33 then delete RDMA-core before the upgrade, or just wipe the system clean and start from scratch. For various reasons though, I would much rather not do the latter if at all possible.

From what I can remember, my system is the following, if the information is necessary:

- OS: Fedora Workstation 33/34 (before/after upgrade) running Cinnamon DE
- Kernel(s): 5.13.6-100.fc33.x86_64, 5.13.5-100.fc33.x86_64, 5.13.4-100.fc33.x86_64, (all three kernel versions are available in grub, but I use the latest by default)
- File system: BTRFS
- CPU: AMD 3700x
- RAM: 32GB DDR4
- GPU: AMD rx5700xt
- GPU driver: mesa (don't remember specific version, probably the latest)

Thanks!

EDIT: So looking into it further today, I found that my ram has bad sectors. I'm thinking that the system must have crashed during the upgrade, causing the boot/efi partition to be wiped or become corrupted. Now I just have to figure out how to either rebuilt it or recreate it. The ram being bad definitely answers some questions I had about a few issues I've been having here and there.

This turned out to be a much different issue than I originally thought, so I'm not sure if I should update the title or just delete the question. If it matters, I guess let me know.

Comment: The rdma-core issue just made `dnf` transactions fail, it didn’t break your ability to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the RAM, you probably could just boot off a rescue image, chroot into the Fedora build and regenerate the initramfs with `dracut -f <image> <kernel-version>` .